# deducing function template specialization when taking address

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand the rules for function template argument deduction in the case where all arguments are defaulted.  Under 13.10.1 (Explicit template argument specification), the standard (C++20) says:

— when the address of a function is taken, when a function initializes a reference to function, or when a pointer to member function is formed, ... If all of the template arguments can be deduced, they may all be omitted; in this case, the empty template argument list <> itself may also be omitted.

However, in the fourth line of the code snippets below, compilers (gcc, MSVC) seem to insist on having the empty angle brackets.  Is this non-conformance or have I missed something ? (In this example, the issue doesn't matter, but the question arose in a context where it does matter).

```
template <typename T = int> void f(T) {}
void (*p)(int) = f;  //ok
auto a = f<>;  //ok
auto b = f; //error, can't deduce

void g() {}
auto c = g; //OK
```

Comment: `void (*c)(int) = f;` works.

Comment: That's already there (line 2)

Comment: Sorry, I mend `void (*c)(float) = f;` works too. To elaborate, line 2 and this example can deduce the `T` from the type. `f<>` explicitly says to use the default `int`. But in `auto b = f` there is nothing to deduce types from. You are saying: deduce the type of `f` from `b` and deduce the type of `b` from `f`.

Comment: `auto b = f;` can't deduce the template parameter; there are an infinite number of possibilities.  The `f<>` deduces the template parameter to be `int` because it is deduced to the defaulted `= int`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow actually there's a deduction rule that makes your sample compilable. Overloaded function can implicitly cast to deduced pointer type. In bad old days you'd need an explicit (static) cast. But that rule is a bit relaxed nowadays.

Comment: @Red.Wave Are you saying `auto b = f;` should compile? Or are you saying you can write it another way so it compiles?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow nop. What is the type?

Comment: @Red.Wave It doesn't have a type and fails to compile. That's what the question is about.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow but you gave an example with a `float` input.

Comment: @Red.Wave Sure. As soon as you specify a type everything is fine.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I remember it was not always so easy. There has been some relaxation of rules - probably for `std::function` to be easier to use, but I cannot give the reference.

Comment: I've edited the question to add a case which casts doubt on the explanation that there is no way to deduce the type.  The type is deduced fine in line 6.  But in line 4 the compilers seem not to be able to deduce the type even though the standard says the template angle brackets can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

The compilers are correct: `auto a = f<>;` is well-formed and `auto b = f;` is ill-formed. This is due to the rules about `auto`, combined with the rules about the address of the function template name `f`.

As described in [[dcl.type.auto.deduct]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.type.auto.deduct#4), the `auto` type for the variable definitions is found in a way like template argument deduction done for a hypothetical function template using a template type parameter in its function parameter:

```
template <typename U> void auto_deducer(U);
auto a = f<>; // auto becomes the U deduced for auto_deducer(f<>)
auto b = f;   // auto becomes the U deduced for auto_deducer(f)
```

In [[temp.deduct.type]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.type#4) paragraphs 4 and 5:

> In certain contexts, however, the value [of a template argument] does not participate in type deduction, but instead uses the values of template arguments that were either deduced elsewhere or explicitly specified. If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced contexts and is not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.
>
> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> - ...
> - A function parameter for which the associated argument is an overload set, and one or more of the following apply:
>
>   - ...
>   - the overload set supplied as an argument contains one or more function templates.
> - ...

So for both `a` and `b`, the template argument deduction used to determine the type of `auto` fails. Since it's not true that "all of the template arguments can be deduced", we're not allowed to omit the empty `<>` syntax.

But we're not entirely done yet, because the same paragraph [[temp.arg.explicit]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.arg.explicit#4) you quoted has some relevant additional text:

> Trailing template arguments that can be deduced or obtained from default *template-arguments* may be omitted from the list of explicit *template-arguments*. A trailing template parameter pack.... If all of the template arguments can be deduced, they may all be omitted; in this case, the empty template argument list `<>` itself may also be omitted. In contexts where deduction is done and fails, or in contexts where deduction is not done, if a template argument list is specified and it, along with any default template arguments, identifies a single function template specialization, then the *template-id* is an lvalue for the function template specialization.

For the definition of both `a` and `b`, the `f<>` or `f` expression is in a non-deduced context, so "deduction is not done". (The template argument deduction for the hypothetical `auto_deducer(f<>)` then fails, but that's for the overall `auto_deducer` call, after the part actually involving `f<>` determined that the type deduction step should not be done with that argument at all.) In `auto a = f<>;`, "a template argument list is specified" and using the default template argument "identifies a single function template specialization" `f<int>`, so the paragraph's final sentence applies and the *template-id* names `f<int>` after all. In `auto b = f;` no template argument list is specified (and `f` is not a *template-id*), so the sentence can't apply.

An actual call like the statement `f();` is fine because template argument deduction happens, uses the default template argument, and succeeds without the complication of `auto`. Converting expression `f` to a specific target pointer-to-function type is fine, because that will deduce the template parameter `T` from the target type, and the default template argument doesn't get involved.

Another confirmation this behavior is intended is found in a non-normative note in [[over.over]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.over#3). The [over.over] section applies when lookup for a name (like `f` or `f<>`) gives an overload set comprising one or more functions and/or function templates and the name expression is not followed by a function call argument list:

> For each function template designated by the name, template argument deduction is done, and if the argument deduction succeeds, the resulting template argument list is used to generate a single function template specialization, which is added to the set of selected functions considered. [ *Note:* As described in [temp.arg.explicit], if deduction fails and the function template name is followed by an explicit template argument list, the *template-id* is then examined to see whether it identifies a single function template specialization. If it does, the *template-id* is considered to be an lvalue for that function template specialization. The target type is not used in that determination. - *end note* ]

Comment: But with `f<>`, the overload set does not contain a function template, because `f<>` denotes a specialization

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Or possibly a set of specializations. I think you're right, that with `f<>` the `auto_deducer` function doesn't "see" a template in its overload set. I'm a little puzzled about how we determine when the address of template ([temp.deduct.funcaddr]) used as a function parameter ([over.over]) "has a target (type)". In this case there's obviously no type it could reasonably be, but some other cases get trickier.

Answer (score 1):

> Trailing template arguments that can be deduced or obtained from default template-arguments
> may be omitted from the list of explicit template-arguments. [...] If all of the template
> arguments can be deduced, they may all be omitted; in this case, the empty template argument list <>
> itself may also be omitted.

Note the last sentence, as opposed to the first sentence, does *not* say "deduced *or obtained from default template-arguments*". Deducing and obtaining from default template-arguments are two different things. This may or may not be a wording defect in the standard.